# Clicking on a link in JavaFX using WebEngine.executeScript function not working

Tags: java, javafx-2

I need help figuring out how to correctly click on a link using javaFx WebEngine.executeScript.
I tried the code: `webEngine.executeScript("document.querySelectorAll(\"a[ajaxify^='/ajax/messaging/composer.php?']\")[0].click();");`

However every time i run my application the following error is generated when executing the above code. The error is as follows:

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1438)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:811)
    at javafxapplication2.MainController$4.run(MainController.java:201)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I also verified that the object exists but for some reason calling the click() function on it is not working. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try the js code snippet in a browser together with firebug.

Comment: I did that and it works fine. I think the problem is because WebEngine's browser removes the click event from hyperlinks so calling the javascript click() function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using javafx 8, but it should be the same idea. If you create a MouseEvents object, you should be able to click on any element.

```
this.webEngine.executeScript("(function () {" +
            "var element = document.querySelector('a');" +
            "var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();" +
            "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
            "evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window," +
            "1, 0, 0, bounds.left, bounds.top," +
            "false, false, false, false," +
            "0, null);" +
            "element.dispatchEvent(evt);" +
            "}());");
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running your [executeScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-) call before your document is loaded.

To know when a document is loaded, you can add a listener on the [document property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty--) or the WebEngine loadworker state property (for a [SUCCEEDED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html#SUCCEEDED) state), you can see an example of the loadworker solution in the [WebEngine javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

```
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
. . .
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<State>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    // execute script here . . . .
                }
            }
        });
webEngine.load("http://javafx.com");
```